# Infinitives after "mental processes"

Tags: infinitive

According to my grammar book, verbs such as *glauben, meinen,* and *behaupten* can be followed by an infinitive clause.
Does the following example apply this correctly?

> Er meint, es gut zu sein.

Something tells me this isn't quite right or just wouldn't be used.

Comment: Ditch the “es” and your example is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

Please note: even if you ditch the 'es', this **doesn't mean** what you would expect from English! An infinitival clause after such a verb implicitly reuses the main subject as its own subject. Therefore,

> Er meint gut zu sein = He thinks *himself* to be good.

To express "He considers *it* to be good" you would use

> Er findet, *dass es gut ist*.

or more idiomatically

> Er findet es gut / Er hält es für gut.